# Number days in a Date Range

Tags: sql, oracle, date-range, days

So in PL/SQL, how do I can I number the days in a date range in a select statement? I want my results to be something like:

DAY |  calc_field1 |   calc_field1 |etc

1   |     XXX     |      YYY |etc

2   |     XXX     |      YYY |etc

3    |    XXX      |     YYY |etc

4    |    XXX      |     YYY |etc

Where the days start with 1 at the beginning date of a range and end on the last day, row for each day.

### EDIT:

Found a solution here:
[Range of dates with PL/SQL](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/date_range.html)

And then modified that code a bit to get this query:

`select dt_range.column_value, rownum
from table (
  cast ( date_range(
      (select begin_date from table where id = 1),
      (select end_date from table where id = 1)
    ) as date_table)
  ) dt_range 
    order by
  dt_range.column_value;`

Comment: i think u want: select row_number() over (order by date_col) as "DAY", x, y, z from my_table

Comment: Yeah, not really. The begin date and end date for the range is in one row in the table.

Comment: Normally, you would do this with a recursive CTE or `connect` statement.